# React router check referring route in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using the React router, is there any way to check the referring route inside a function component ?

So if user navigates to /path2 (Comp2) from /path1 (Comp1), I want that in Comp2, it should give me path1.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down state using the `<Link>` component and `useLocation` hook from react router, in this case a pathname:

```
const Comp1 = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <Link to={{
        pathname: '/path2',
        state: { prevPath: location.pathname }
      }}
    >
      Example Link
    </Link>
  );
}
```

and then in your `Comp2`

```
const Comp2 = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>My previous location was: {location.state.prevPath}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Is it possible to achieve without passing it down explicitly...I mean when we do history.back(), react knows where to route....So i just need the same info/path name